# Problem with Facebook on Midori

Tags: 16.04, facebook, midori

When I log into Facebook on Midori, everything loads normally except for the search bar and the friend request/messages/notifications icons. They load underneath the Facebook button and on the left side, partially cut off.

Comment: Maybe you should report that to Midori devs.

Comment: Maybe you could point me in the direction to do so

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. Some people have already reported this:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/1458930
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/1559617

You should click on these links after logging in on Launchpad to mark that you're having problems as well: the more people who do so, the faster it gets resolved.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/1458930/+affectsmetoo
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/1559617/+affectsmetoo